# R Filter a List

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter a list in R that has length 4. Each of the 4 "sections" of the list has an id unique to that section, so each section has a row with ID = 1. I want to create a new list that has 4 rows, where each observation has ID = 1. This is what I have come up with so far, but I cannot use the R filter command on a list and I am unsure of what to try next:

```
filter.list <- ex1.list[lapply(ex1.list, filter(ex1.list, id == 1))]
```

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you revise your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (i.e. add sample data).

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you trying to use `dplyr::filter` or `stats::filter` or `base::Filter`? What do you have loaded?

Comment: lapply(ex1.list, function(x) filter(x, id == 1))